# How to increase the speed of Android Studio emulator on macbookpro 2012 i7?

Tags: android, macos, android-emulator

Some users save experienced emulator stability issues with this driver version. As a result. This appears everytime i open an emulator and when it opens its too slow alyhough i have a ram og 16gb and core i7 macbookpro 2012

Comment: try using vscode since it is a lighter ide and use an actual phone as an emulator so you macbook can run it. You can get an android virtual device that is a bit older so that it takes less resources

Answer (score -1):

<strike>Throw away</strike> Retire that outdated piece of hardware and get a desktop computer instead of a notebook. Unless it can run OpenGL (which often isn't the case with an on-board GPU), the emulator performance will be poor. Alternatively, just use a physical device for testing.